# Getting 'unauthorized_client' with Power Platform Custom Connector using OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, connection, powerapps, power-platform

I am trying to build a Custom Connector in the Power Platform to connect to the BMC Helix (formerly Remedy) system to create work orders and such. I am using OAuth2 and was given a callback URL, auth URL, token URL, client ID and client secret.

I went to create a connector from scratch. I populated the fields, but I wasn't sure what to put for the 'Refresh URL', so I used the token URL there too.

I am trying to accomplish testing this connector and my successful test would be to get a JWT from doing a POST to the /api/jwt/login endpoint of BMC Helix. It should return a JWT which I can use to make subsequent calls.

Upon testing this, I go to create a connection, but a window opens (which I believe should be a prompt for authentication), but instead it contains an error saying 'unauthorized_client' coming back from the BMC Helix system at the /rsso/oauth2/authorize endpoint. It also contains a property within the URL of redirect_uri = https://global.consent.azure-apim.net/redirect.

Is there something on the Helix side I need to further configure? Not sure why I am getting this....

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need TWO METHODS in your connector. A POST to call the token server, a GET (or another POST) to call the API (using the token received from Call 1).

**One approach I've successfully used in the past is:**

- Use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) to get your token server call working with OAUTH
- Then use Postman to get your subsequent API calls working with the token appended
- Save both requests to a single Postman collection
- Export the Postman collection (as a V1 (deprecated) if I recall correctly)
- Import this collection into PowerApps Custom Connector (create new/import from Postman Collection)

You'll have to massage it a bit after import, but it will give you a good headstart and you're starting from a known-good place (working Postman calls)

Good luck!

Comment: Hi SeaDude. I respect the approach, but sadly I think it may not work. Reason being, is that Postman is going to save the token that's returned into the json file. We need a way to do the actual call to get the token, in Flow. Any attempts to do that results in the error I mentioned.